# TeamCity custom script: How do i find file size? Its not executing the regular batch command

Tags: teamcity

This command is not working in TeamCity custom script. But, its working fine on a batch file

```
FOR %A in ("LargeFile.txt") DO set "size=%~zA"
```

Comment: What is it: Teamcity custom script? And do yo have any errors?

Comment: Error is: teamcity.build.checkoutDir~zA was unexpected at this time.

Comment: and other question? What is it: Teamcity custom script?

Comment: `FOR %A in ("LargeFile.txt") DO set "size=%~zA"` **does not work** in a batch file. From `for /?`: *To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead*

Answer (score 1):

When you write Custom Scripts, you need to escape the `%` which is the char used for Teamcity's parameters.

You need to add an extra `%` to escape them.

Comment: oh forgot to mention that here.I have already escaped it.
FOR %%A in ("LargeFile.txt") DO set "size=%%~zA"